Backtracking in python - The Knight’s tour problem
Problem Statement: Given a N*N board with the Knight placed on the first block of an empty board. Moving according to the rules of chess knight must visit each square exactly once. Print the order of each cell in which they are visited on the chess board. If  there are more than one solutions possible, print all of them.
Input :
N = 8
Output:
0  59  38  33  30  17   8  63
37  34  31  60   9  62  29  16
58   1  36  39  32  27  18   7
35  48  41  26  61  10  15  28
42  57   2  49  40  23   6  19
47  50  45  54  25  20  11  14
56  43  52   3  22  13  24   5
51  46  55  44  53   4  21  12

I tried a recursive solution using backtracking but do not quite understand what could be the problem with this piece of code. Could someone please help. Thanks a lot!
for n=2,3,4 it produces an empty list which is expected.
and for n=5, it produces the following unexpected output:
[[[0, '.', '.', '.', '.'], ['.', '.', '.', '.', '.'], ['.', '.', '.', '.', '.'], ['.', '.', '.', '.', '.'], ['.', '.', '.', '.', '.']], [[0, '.', '.', '.', '.'], ['.', '.', '.', '.', '.'], ['.', '.', '.', '.', '.'], ['.', '.', '.', '.', '.'], ['.', '.', '.', '.', '.']]] ..continues
for n=8, the program keeps running and does not seem to produce an output for a long time
def knight(n):
  xy_movements = [(2,1),(2,-1),(-2,1),(-2,-1),(1,2),(-1,2),(1,-2),(-1,-2)]
  board = [["."]*n for _ in range(n)]
  board[0][0]=0
  current_x=0
  current_y=0
  result=[]

  def backtrack(num):    
    nonlocal n,current_x,current_y
    if num==(n*n)-1:
      result.append(board)
      return
    else:
      for move in xy_movements:
        if current_x+move[0]<0 or current_x+move[0]>=n or\
           current_y+move[1]<0 or current_y+move[1]>=n or\
           board[current_x+move[0]][current_y+move[1]] !=".":
          continue
        else:
          current_x+=move[0]
          current_y+=move[1]
          board[current_x][current_y] = num+1
          backtrack(num+1)
        
        board[current_x][current_y] = "."
        current_x -= move[0]
        current_y -= move[1]

  backtrack(0)
  return result


You mention that there is a problem with this code, but you don't explain what the problem is. Please edit your question to explain why this code doesn't do what you expect it to. E.g. does it throw an exception? Does it appear to run forever and generate no output? Does it generate incorrect output?

@LukeWoodward Done. Have edited my code and included the output that i am getting.

Doesn't work. Try copy'n'pasting the code into a file and running it. Also see [mcve]. BTW: Take a look at PEP 8, it mandates four spaces indent. Adhering to these standards makes it easier for others to quickly and correctly read and understand your code.

For testing, I would start with chess boards with side lengths 1 (trivially solvable), 2, 3 (both unsolvable) and the smalles larger one that is solvable. This will make it easier to understand and debug.

@trincot n=4 does not seem to have a solution. n=1 has one; corrected that

Alright! Also why is result a list? Are you looking to find all possible tours?

@trincot Since the backtrack function works recursively, it is intended to append all those board configurations that have the final number as (n*n)-1

the backtrack function is recursively called in the else block as backtrack(num+1)

But that is not stated in the challenge. I think you confuse that one tour consists of n*n positions, which is just one board. You are not supposed to store n*n boards in the result (nor does your code do that), but only the final board after those n*n positions have been calculated. And then you should stop. The challenge does not ask for alternative boards.

@trincot Aah okay, yes actually ! I just went ahead to try producing all the possible outputs

OK, but then please edit your question, as then you are solving a different challenge.

done! included a line to include all possible solutions

Fine, but now the example input/output is not complete (nor could it be in practical terms): it just lists one solution.

The problem is that result.append(board) will append the only board you have, while your backtracking algorithm will continue to update that board, and at the very end of the algorithm will have taken back all moves it did. So then board is empty, except for the first 0 that was placed and never removed. This means that in result you now reference an almost empty board, even though solutions were found.
The solution is simple: take a copy of the board, and append that board to the result list:
            result.append([row[:] for row in board])

This will solve the issue you mention when calling knight(5). For boards larger than 6, you will just have a problem that is too great: there are 19,591,828,170,979,904 solutions for an 8x8 board, so don't hope to get that in a few seconds. Your PC will probably not have enough memory to collect that many boards, let be you can wait for it.

Sorry i had a query. Doesn't result append all those boards which have a final number as n*n-1? Could you clarify a bit more please

Yes, I confirm. It is the same as saying that result appends all completed boards. What clarification is needed? If you don't copy the board, you are appending a reference to the same board over and over again, so that all elements in result are actually the same board, which is the board you are constantly updating during the algorithm.

Would really appreciate some more clarification on why result.append(board) doesn't work as intended. Thank you for the answer above!

But it works as intended. At least as intended by the specification. Just ask yourself: how many boards do you have allocated in your program? The answer is : 1. Appending that 1 board to a list does not somehow create a new board. It is still that single board.

Isn't The backtracking algo editing the board at each step. When it gets 24 for n=5, it should have displayed all the other number as well

Imagine you have a real chessboard, and you place a new knight physically on the board at each square (and each knight has a unique number). At some point you find that you have filled the whole board. You place the chessboard will all pieces on it in a box, thinking you have "saved" the board. But then you continue removing knights from that chessboard and try different setups, and then clear all pieces from it. What is the chessboard in the box? It is empty. The fact that you placed the board in the box didn't do anything significant to the board. Same with result.append(board)

"it should have displayed all the other number": But you didn't display it at that moment. You delayed the displaying until the every end, when you had already removed the pieces again from that board.

Thank you very much for your insights. I get it!
